# CSS Flexbox - Same height when a column contains multiple parts?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple question. I have a basic flex-box layout.  One column takes up 2/3 of the layout, the other takes up a third.  Both of them have a purple semi-transparent header (.85) with their contents are in an opaque black box.

http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/XdoBqL

```css
body {
   background: url('http://www.amazingwallpaperz.com/wp-content/uploads/Black-and-Purple-Abstract-Cool-Backgrounds-Wallpaper.jpg') center center;
    background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  
}
#featuredSlide, #featuredSlide img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #fff;
}


.sect {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 32%;
   -webkit-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
 margin: 30px;  text-align: center;
}
.sect + .sect {
   margin-left: 10px;
}
.sect.feat {width: 65%;
  -webkit-flex: 2;
          flex: 2;

}

.sect .cont {
  background:#414141;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

}

.sect h2 {
  background:#414141;
    background-color: rgba(52,41,109,.85);
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 30px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<head><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

<div class="sect feat">  
 <h2> Featured Guests &amp; Programming</h2>

<div class="cont">

<!-- SLIDE SHOW -->
 <div id="featuredSlide" class="owl-carousel">
<img src="http://placehold.it/800x300/5d64a8">
  
</div> <!-- CLOSING SLIDE SHOW DIV TAG --></div>
</div>

<div class="sect">  
 <h2> News </h2>

<div class="cont">Some thrilling article</div>
</div>


</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
  
</body>
```

Both `.sect` elements are the same height.  I want both `.sect .cont` elements to be the same height.  I know I can make them *look* the same height by setting a `background-color` to `.sect` but that will ruin the transparency of my headers.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use this javascript plugin: [matchHeights](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). You don't need to write any javascript just include the script and add `data-mh="cont"` to each `<div class="cont">`. You might have a hell of a time doing this with css only

Comment: @zgood Yeah, I was considering using js to grab the inner height of `.feat .cont` and making them match but fortunately @Hunter Turner knew better.  Hooray for SO :D

Comment: yea his solution seems to be the better approach. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `flex-direction: column;` to your `.sect` class, and give your `.cont` class a `flex-grow: 1`. This will make the `.cont` div's take up the remaining height of the `.sect` class.

```
.sect {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cont {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/mPaGdq)

Comment: Best answer goes to you! Thank you so much, y'know, I swear I tried that but I'm not sure.  Anyway, that you so much for helping this flexbox newbie :D

Comment: Haha, thanks! No problem, glad to help! Here is a resource that I use for flexbox :) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can do this with css only. Add the following to your .sect properties:

```
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border-radius:5px;
```

and add this to make the heights match:

```
.sect + .sect .cont::after {
  background: #414141 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  height: 3000px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You should also then be able to take out your border radii from the h2 and .cont as well.